# How do you get name of every video in a playlist from YouTube in Python using pytube, pafy or another module?

Tags: python, pytube, pafy

I am trying to make a converter for my own personal use as a project. I have been using pytube and pafy but they don't seem to get the names of the individual videos from a playlist on YouTube.

Can anyone help me find a solution? (I don't have a code as it is connected with a bunch of other files and GUI's)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created my own solution for this:

```
from pytube import Playlist
play_list = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4o29bINVT4EG_y-k5jGoOu3-Am8Nvi10")
print(len(play_list))

for link in play_list:
    print(link)
for video in play_list.videos:
    name = video.title
    print(name)
```

This prints the link of every video within a playlist and also the title of each video in a playlist.

Comment: Awesome! Works for me.